# C prime factorization (loop failure?)

Tags: c, for-loop

I've been looking into this simple piece of code for 1.5 hrs now and do not find the mistake. I start going crazy ;)

Could anyone of you with a fresh mind and view give me a little hint, where I might have the mistake in? (I am relatively new to C)

The problem is: The code works fine for most of the numbers I entered and tested, but accidentically I found a number that does not work: 3486118 (or 55777888 which is a multiple of it) It goes right for the first loop(s), but after factor 2 it becomes an endless loop.

Here is my code: (any help is greatly appreciated)

```
// Program calculates prime factors of entered number and returns them

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    long int num, num_cp;
    long int product=1;

    /*prime number array up to 100.000*/
    long int prime[] = {2, 3, **[...cut out MANY numbers...]** 99971, 99989, 99991};

    printf("Please enter a positive integer:\n");
    scanf("%li", &num);//55777888 or 3486118 not working... why?
    //copy the entered number to keep the original for comparison with "product" and "break;" if equal
    num_cp=num;

    printf("prime factorization of %li:\n\n", num);

    for (int i=0; i<sizeof(prime); i++) {
        if (num_cp%prime[i]==0) {
            num_cp/=prime[i];
            product*=prime[i];
            if (product==num) {
                printf("%li\n\n", prime[i]);
                break;
            }
            printf("%li*", prime[i]);

            //If prime factor found but "product" is still not equal to "num" reset loop counter "i" to -1 (==0 in next loop)
            i=-1;
        }
    }
    printf("END");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the array of primes? Maybe it is missing some / has nonprime elements?

Comment: `i<sizeof(prime)` should be `i<sizeof(prime)/sizeof *prime` so that `i` "goes to" every element but no more

Comment: 1. @mtjanic: The prime number list I copied from some Webpage. 2. could you explain "i<sizeof(prime)/sizeof *prime" more detailed, please? As far as I understand, the loop will end anyway when "i" exceeds "sizeof(prime)" ?

Comment: As @pmg mentioned, sizeof() doesn't return the number of elements in array, but its memory size.

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you, I thought it would be the no. of elements... okay I will correct this first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prime factors of 55777888 are 2·2·2·2·2·1743059, where the last factor is too large to be contained in your list.

You can fix this in your code: When the product is equal to the product of the prime factors you have found, `num_cp` is 1. If `num_cp` is greater than one after you have exhausted your prime list, it is a factor of `num`. If `num/num_cp` is smaller than the largest prime you have checked, you can assume that the remaining value of `num_cp` is a prime. If it wasn't you'd have found more factors earlier.

You can fix this by adding an additional check after your main loop:

```
if (num_cp > 1) printf("%li\n\n", num_cp);
```

(If `long int` is a 64-bit number on your system, you're still not safe: The remaining factor might be made up of several numbers that are not in your array.)

Finally: Resetting the `for` loop counter so that the loop starts over isn't a good idea. It always starts from the beginning and re-checks primes that you have already checked. And it just isn't natural program flow, which makes it hard to read. A `while` loop instead of the inner `if` block would be more natural in my opinion.

**Edit**: To illustrate:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long int num;

    /* prime number array up to 100.000 */
    long int prime[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31};
    int nprime = sizeof(prime) / sizeof(*prime);

    num = 55;

    printf("%li == ", num);

    for (int i = 0; i < nprime; i++) {
        long int p = prime[i];

        if (num <= 1) break;

        while (num % p == 0) {
            num /= prime[i];
            printf("%li", p);
            if (num > 1) printf(" * ");
        }
    }

    if (num > 1) printf("%li", num);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Things to note:

- Instead of resetting the main loop counter `i`, a `while` loop is used, which consumes all repetitions of the same factor. If a prime `p` doesn't divide the number, the `while` loop isn't entered, just like an `if` clause.
- I've removed the copy of `num` and used `num` throughout, mainly to remove clutter. I've also removed the `product`. Your logic that all prime factors should multiply to the original number, is good. But it also works the other way round: After dividing the number by all primes, we are left with 1. And we have to divide the number anyways. By removing the product, we have to keep track of only one variable instead of two.
- I've moved the `break` condition to the front, so we catch negative numbers and 0 early.

That said, your way to code isn't wrong, just maybe a bit unusual in places.

Comment: Thank you! I see... that is what happens if you look too much into the same piece of code over and over... I did think of everything, but not that the next prime number could be too large to be in my list -.- secondly: The For-loop reset is on purpose, because I HAVE to check for the same prime factor again and again, otherwise 2·2·2·2·... would not work, if I didn't check factor 2 over and over again? But I am more than willing to learn from the community here! As I said, I'm new to C, just trying to get into it (starting studies in September) Thank you for the final hint :) - great forum!

Comment: I know that the reset is on purpose. It's just not a good way to achieve what you want. (It is so unusual that I missed it on my first reading.) A better variant would be to repeatedly divide the number in a while loop. Of course, you'd have to check the product after the inner while. Otherwise the `break` would break the `while`, not the main `for` loop.

Answer (score 5):

"I've been looking into this simple piece of code for 1.5 hrs now and do not find the mistake. I start going crazy ;)"

Don't.  Leave it.  Go away and eat a pizza.  Veg out in front of your favourite movie.  Have a shower.  Aim for a new high-score on 2048 (or whatever).  Your brain gets stuck in a rut and you are no longer seeing your code.  You are only seeing what you think your code is.

When you get your brain out of the rut, then -- and only then -- go back and actually read the code you wrote.  Not the code you think you wrote, but the code you actually wrote.  Yes, they are different.

Comment: I badly want to +1 this.

Comment: You are so right! I should have done that. But maybe you know the feeling of being so close to the answer that you would rather take the well deserved break after fixing it? ;) I will do this now and come back to it later. Thanks for now, guys